# Agent should be located in the same network as the destination node

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to retrieve the Pallet from the Storage and want to place it in a truck for shipment. It is successfully retrieving the Pallet and placing it at a point, where the fork lifters here responsible to pick up and place it on a truck but after they pickup and are ready to move, i am getting an error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: root.[10]: Agent should be located in the same network as the destination node. Current node: Loading Zone, destination node: Loading Point Node

[This is the Error message]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJV4o.png

[Logic part]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBp1n.png

[calling Truck]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyKbP.png

[seize]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZemg.png

[Forklifters]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjVSZ.png

[RetailTrucks]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s84F2.png

[MoveTo]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5n9f.png

Comment: As the error suggests, loadingZone and loadingPointNode are not in the same network..on the left side, under Projects, expand all and you will see that you have different networks instead of one.

Comment: yes, they are not in the same network (ie. network, network2 ) but i have provided the path which is well connected to the nodes.  Else how do i link its network....and one more thing, the incoming trucks are not in the same network but are running perfectly.

Comment: Now, i have provided the paths. It's working now, but as they are in different Networks the fork lifters are not following the path.

Comment: what would be the best idea to follow if the nodes are not in the same network?

Comment: Hey, welcome to SOF. Best either edit your original question or open a new one, this place does not work like a forum, it's a Q&A place. Very happy to help, some guidance https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow